# Multiple-domains on WAMP localhost

Tags: apache-2.2, localhost, domain

If you're reading my question, thanks, I appreciate your help

I'm using Wamp on Windows Vista.

I've created 2 project folders:

```
www/project1/ 
www/project2/
```

My virtual hosts file looks like this:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/project1/"
    ServerName project1.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/project2/"
    ServerName project2.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Can someone advise how I can go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the DNS for those domains is pointing elsewhere, you will have to add entries to your hosts file for them if you want them to resolve locally, eg:

```
127.0.0.1 first.com
127.0.0.1 second.com
```

Of course, if you want the whole world to connect to your local server when they visit those domains, you would need to edit the DNS settings for the domains.

Comment: That's not enough though, because all this does is take me to the webroot /wamp/www/. But I'm trying to forward first.com and second.com to the /first/ and /second/ folders which are one level deeper within the web root, hence my attempt to use Virtual Hosts and httpd-vhosts.conf. Any ideas why it's taking me to the root and not to the folders inside it?

Comment: Ok I take that comment back. It looks like it was acting up because it looks like I had to restart Apache. I'm doing some testing now before I give the final verdict, and will update the thread when done.

Answer (score 0):

Umm, I don't think that really answered his question?

Try following this tutorial, and let me know if you still can't get it working:

http://www.kintek.com.au/web-design-blog/configuring-multiple-domains-within-wamp-for-local-development/